# How to grab and change css properties or text content of HTML elements which are dynamically or periodically added into HTML page by javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

The Javascript code in the below HTML page adds new images into the page periodically but I can't see them in view page source. How can I grab and change CSS properties or text content of HTML elements which are dynamically or periodically added into HTML page by javascript code? Is it possible to make them seen in view page source? Thank you for answer.

I couldn't do anything to obtain any result as a solution to the problem I described. Because I think the solution may be in another js concept which I hadn't meet any example in web.

```js
setInterval(getData, 2000);

async function getData() {
  await fetch('https://unsplash.it/600/400')
    .then(res => res.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      let img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      document.querySelector('body').appendChild(img);
    });
}
```

Comment: You won't see the dynamic content in 'View source', as that's the HTML which was included when the page loaded, but you *will* see them in the DOM inspector, right click the image, then 'Inspect'

Comment: Also, any CSS loaded in the page will be applied to dynamic content, so you don't need to update/change anything on the elements.

Comment: I wondered if all the newly added html elements which are dynamically appended are also accessable like the html elements of a static html page. Are there any difference for DOM methods we must consider when compared to static html dom. Can we grab their text content with an indexer and apply regex search for each of them for example.

Answer (score 0):

When you inspect a page via an inspector you view will see the rendered Document Object Model which will display the img you have loaded. If you view the page source you will only see the source of the page without your images -  this is kind of the default state of the page

To do what I think you want you would need to send the image url to the backend of your site. You could then use something (e.g. php) to render the images you have saved in the backend - you would need somewhere to store (a database probably) the urls of the images and a way to retrieve and render these.

Then with javascript you could cause the page to refresh and render your new image so it would appear in source of the page.  The affect should be similar to doing what you are currently doing with just javascript but you might need to take account of latency between the images getting save then re-rendered - perhaps by adding a spinner of some kind.